# PHP Multidimensional object menu

Tags: php, loops, object, multidimensional-array

I have made function to get multidemnsional menu from database.

```
public function get_menu($parent=0,$vis=1) {
        $categories = array();
        $this->db->from('ci_categories');
        $this->db->where('cat_child',$parent);
        $this->db->where('cat_vis',1);
        $this->db->order_by('cat_order');
        $q = $this->db->get();

        $result = $q->result();

        $i=0;
        foreach($result as $mainCategory) {
            $mainCategory->cat_subcategories = $this->get_menu($mainCategory->cat_id);
            $categories[$i] = $mainCategory;
            $i++;
        }

        return $categories;
    }
```

It is working but I would like to print out the menus. For now I can print main menu and one child with this code:

```
if (count($menu) > 0) {
    foreach($menu as $menu_item) {
    $link = anchor("category/".$menu_item->cat_url, $menu_item->cat_name);

    echo "<li>$link";

    if (!empty($menu_item->cat_subcategories)) {
       echo "<ul>";
       foreach($menu_item->cat_subcategories as $subcat) {
         $sub_link = anchor("category/".$subcat->cat_url, $subcat->cat_name);
         echo "<li>$sub_link</li>";
    }
           echo "</ul>";
        }

    echo "</li>";
        }
    }
```

It is working too but how could I print out even 3rd or 4th submenu without manualy writing those foreach and ifs ? Thanks

Comment: use recursion to go all the way through your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a recursive function...

Something like:

```
function showMenu($menu) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($menu as $menu_item) {
        $link = anchor("category/".$menu_item->cat_url, $menu_item->cat_name);
        echo "<li>$link";
        if (!empty($menu_item->cat_subcategories)) showMenu($menu_item->cat_subcategories);
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

That's an idea ;)